# Setting Variables in Variables in Batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to efficiently name variables `a1` through `a9` with `!%f%!` through `!%q%!`.
I tried creating a for loop to complete this:

```
set w=0
for %%K in (f g h i k l m o q) do (
    set /a w+=1
    set /a b%w%=%!%%K!%
    set /a a%w%=!b%w%!%%13
)
```

The error is that there is a missing operator, so I'm assuming that the parenthesis and exclamation marks are being misread. How would I go about fixing this problem?

**TL;DR**

Make:

```
set /a a1=!%f%!%%13
...
set /a a9=!%q%!%%13
```

...more efficient.

To clarify, %f% is equal to say 4D and %4D% is equal to 9.

I need the modulus of 9 and 13 as the a1.

Comment: Won't fix it, but instead of doing `set /a w=w+1` - you should do `set /a w+=1`.

Comment: Is that like the x++ incrementer for batch?

Comment: Pretty much. What is the point of setting your b1 through b9 variables?

Comment: I was just trying to eliminate a pair of percent signs in an attempt to fix the problem, and does set /a w-=1 decrement w?

Comment: Also, setting w to 0 is not necessary at the start. setting an empty variable using /a and +=1 will set the variable to 1.

Comment: try it for yourself - yeah, it does.

Comment: @unclemeat - but it is not a bad idea to explicitly initialize w, just in case it has some other value from some previous operation.

Comment: Yeah, I added that back into my answer. It definitely is.

Comment: I am completely lost as to what you are attempting. Please show values of all variables involved, and show the desired outcome. Also, please indicate whether delayed expansion is enabled or enabled within your script.

Comment: Delayed expansion is enabled and as for the desired, it's in the TL;DR

Comment: What the hell is TL:DR? Is there a variable named `f` with a numeric value? It is not at all clear what your intent is. Provide some variable initial states, as well as expected final states. Don't just give code, because we don't know if your code is correct.

Comment: What the hell is wrong with your attitude? Its means Too long;didn't read and its a pretty popular term. As for the variable f, it has a string value and that string value variable has a numerical value.


f is a random string 4D; 4D is 9;the expected value is 9%%13

Comment: Some of us are old farts that do not know a lot of "popular" lingo.

Comment: My apologies, and also I made a silly typo in my question, I need the actual numerical answer of the modulus equation and the answer below doesn't seem to cover that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe at least one problem you are facing, based on your comment below your question, is that a variable name of `4D` will be interpreted by `SET /A` as the number 4 followed by variable D, which would be invalid.

Another issue you have is that the expansion of `%w%` will be a constant value within the loop. You need delayed expansion `!w!` instead.

I believe this is what you want.

```
set w=0
for %%K in (f g h i k l m o q) do (
  set /a w+=1
  for %%V in (!%%K!) do set /a a!w!=!%%V!%%13
)
```

If none of your variable names begin with a number, then you could simply use

```
set w=0
for %%K in (f g h i k l m o q) do (
  set /a w+=1
  set /a a!w!=!%%K!%%13
)
```

I try to avoid using a number as the leading character for a variable name for two reasons:

1) SET /A will not expand the variable properly, as you are experiencing in your question.

2) Normal expansion of `%4D%` would be interpreted as value of argument `%4`, followed by D, followed by a `%` that would be stripped from the result.

Comment: So is this generally how I can fix my problem with variables starting with numbers in any case? Because right now I am naming the variables a2D, a4C, etc. and then making them substrings.

Comment: And I'm slightly unclear on the usage of !%%K! instead of just %%K in the for %%V loop

Comment: See my updated answer as to why a variable name starting with a number is to be avoided. The value of `%%K` is f. I use `!%%K!` to get the string `4D` into `%%V` so that I can then use `!%%V!` which equates to `!4D!`.

Answer (score 0):

```
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
set w=0
for %%K in (f g h i k l m o q) do (
    set /a w+=1
    set a!w!=^^!%%%%K%%^^!%%%%13
)

:: as a test
echo !a5!
```

This should do the trick for you. Carat `^` is the batch escape character.

Comment: That cannot possibly work - the expansion of `%w%` will remain constant within the loop. Delayed expansion is needed. Also, I don't know what you are attempting with the carets - you cannot escape a `%` with a caret.

Comment: Yeah, realized my various obvious problems after testing it.

Comment: The output that I am getting is: !%f%!%%13

Comment: I need the actual result of the operation

Comment: So if `%f%` expands to `foo` and `!foo!` expands to `bar` you're expecting the output to be `bar%%13`?